# Generate SQLite data as button (SWT)

Tags: java, user-interface, button, grid, swt

I need to generate buttons from SQLite data, but on 100% size like this image:

[image]

The problem is that my main layout is absolute :(

```
    TabFolder tabFolder = new TabFolder(shell, SWT.NONE);
    //tabFolder.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    tabFolder.setBounds(10, 319, 740, 342);

    TabItem tbtmPizzas = new TabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
    tbtmPizzas.setText("Members");

    Composite composite = new Composite(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
    tbtmPizzas.setControl(composite);


    // for this example, I simply repeated this button with different bounds
    Button button = new Button(composite, SWT.NONE);
    button.setText("Michael");
    button.setBounds(10, 10, 137, 52);
```

Comment: Does your layout have to be absolute? Why not use a GridLayout with padding?

Also, what does it look like in its current state? Please post a screenshot of the problem GUI, too.

Comment: What is your actual question? Do you want to convert this to use layouts?

Comment: My question is, how to obtain this result (on image) from SQLite data? I cannot know the number of button before couting it on SQLite so, how to organize button to hold it like this?

Comment: @user3689117 Do you want to know how to determine a "good" value for the number of columns or do you want to know, in general, how to lay buttons out in a grid?

Comment: @Baz these 2 options sounds fine :D I think the first option is easier so I don't have to change all my code

Comment: @user3689117 Don't get me wrong, you should in any case start using a layout instead of positioning your widget absolutely.

Comment: What layout is a good choice on this case? Grid?

Comment: @OlivierZoletti Since you want all your `Button`s to be of the same width, a `GridLayout` with the second parameter set to `true` sounds like a good choice.

Comment: @Baz Can I use a composite on Grid in my TabFolder ?

Comment: @OlivierZoletti Updated my answer with a `TabFolder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you get things started:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell();
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    TabFolder folder = new TabFolder(shell, SWT.NONE);

    TabItem item = new TabItem(folder, SWT.NONE);
    item.setText("Item");

    Composite content = new Composite(folder, SWT.NONE);
    content.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, true));

    String[] myData = {"This", "is", "some", "random", "data"};

    for (String data : myData)
    {
        Button button = new Button(content, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setText(data);
        button.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    }

    item.setControl(content);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you brooo!!! You know what I was trying? Something like this: Button button = new Button(this, SWT.NONE);
            button.setText(nom);
           
            GridData gd = new GridData();
            gd.horizontalAlignment = GridData.CENTER;
      button.setLayoutData(gd);